# WPF MVVM is there an alternative to IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have several groups of Observable collections of items that are updated on a background thread at a regular interval (30 to 60 seconds).  These collections are displayed through ItemsControls on the View.  The parent and the items within the control have several display attributes tied to the status of each item.

1. Status will determine what shape will be displayed next to the text as well as the stroke and fill color of that shape.
2. Status will determine the background color and text color of the text for that item.
3. Status will determine if a countdown timer is displayed in the item (Timer has no tie back to the viewmodel)
4. Status may determine the border color of the parent container.

I am currently performing this logic in individual IValueConverters for each property.  It works but it feels cumbersome and spread out.  I almost want to somehow subscribe to the PropertyChanged Event in the UI and have it call a single method to render all the display for that item so that all the logic is contained in a single place.  Is there a better way to do this or should I just stick to IValueConverters?

Here is an example of what I have.

The collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<PanelItem> PanelItems1 
{
    get { return panelItems1; }
    set
    {
        panelItems1 = value;
        base.OnPropertyChanged("PanelItems1");
    }
}
```

PanelItem is a small collection of properties that include:  Name, Value (Status), Description.  The ItemsControls is similar to the following:

```
<Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
        BorderBrush="{Binding Path=PanelGroup1.HighestStatus, Converter={StaticResource ParentBorderColorConverter}}"
        BorderThickness="3" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,2,0">
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="First Group" Style="{StaticResource panelTitle}" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PanelItems1, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PanelItemTemplate}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>

        <!-- Here is the Data Template -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PanelItemTemplate">
            <Viewbox MaxHeight="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Hand">
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Path Margin="2,2,2,2" StrokeThickness="2">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <Binding Path="Status" Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource ShapeConverter}" />
                        </Path.Data>
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <Binding Path="Status" Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource ShapeColorConverter}" />
                        </Path.Fill>
                        <Path.Stroke>
                            <Binding Path="Status" Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource ShapeBorderConverter}" />
                        </Path.Stroke>
                    </Path>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the Visual State Manager? You can roll your own control template with the VSM backing up any visual states - obviously it needs to know what it's bound to so it can apply those states conditionally - you could also just use triggers instead of value converters

Comment: Instead of exposing a single Status and apply 3 different converters, you could expose 3 different properties on your VM and do the 3 conversions to give them a value in the VM (or in logic called by the VM)

Comment: Check here for info about VSM http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/02/27/the-visualstatemanager-and-triggers.aspx - there is also relevant info on triggers - I always see value converters as a way to convert values, not to trigger visual state so I try and avoid them on anything cumbersome as they end up being code rather than markup

Comment: @Charleh I hadn't seen this before, very interesting.  I'm reading on it right now.  It looks like its used more for UI interaction events but I might be able to bind it the property on the viewmodel.  It looks like I'd have to add a VSM for each control and then switch visual states based on the View.

Comment: @stijn When you say expose 3 properties on the VM would those properties be the color?  If so it kinda puts the View specfic display knowledge into the ViewModel.

Comment: check Sheridan's answer, it is exactly what I meant. It's not because Color happens to be something that goes on the screen that it can't be in your VM - people take MVVM way to serious and strict sometimes

Comment: @jrandomuser, did you try a markup extension?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just declare a normal class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for your `Status` object? Just add the required properties into it, such as `Geometry`, `Fill` and `Stroke`, etc... if you did that, you wouldn't need any `Converter` classes and you could do something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PanelItemTemplate">
    <Viewbox MaxHeight="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Hand" > 
           <WrapPanel>
                <Path Margin="2,2,2,2" StrokeThickness="2" >
                <Path.Data>
                    <Binding Path="Status.Geometry" Mode="OneWay" />
                </Path.Data>
                <Path.Fill>
                    <Binding Path="Status.Fill" Mode="OneWay" />
                </Path.Fill>
                <Path.Stroke>
                    <Binding Path="Status.Stroke" Mode="OneWay" />
                </Path.Stroke>
            </Path>
            <ContentPresenter  Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0"   />
        </WrapPanel>
    </Viewbox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that properties like `Fill` and `Stroke` represent visual state and shouldn't be a part of your viewmodel if you intend to correctly follow the MVVM pattern.

Comment: 'should' does not mean 'must'

Comment: I like the idea, I can create a class that encompasses that logic.  My question is where does it fit?  The DataContext of the View is set to my ViewModel, the ItemsControl is bound to a collection of items on that ViewModel, how do I interject the new Status class between them?

Comment: I agree with Adi, `Fill` and `Stroke` should not be part of your VM as the view should decide visual state based on the VM contents. You could break the rule, but if you are handing views over to a UX/UI designer and they have to go messing about with viewmodels in order to change the visual state it kind of defeats the whole purpose of MVVM. There are easy ways to get visual state to react to viewmodel properties using triggers or VSM. You can be 'semi-strict' with MVVM but if you can find a way to do it without 'cheating' then you are learning and usually creating a more robust solution.

Comment: However - on a counterpoint - if your VM is application specific and wraps a particular data item, then you could argue that it goes hand in hand with the view. If you are reusing viewmodels then likely it's the wrong approach

Comment: In fact I can see a lot of situation where the ViewModel will contain significant visualization information. Because it is for example the view model of a drawing application, or a chart. How the VIEW is transposint it is another thing, but ther eare edge cases where the ViewModel contains information like that because this is what the viewmodel is about in this particular case.

Comment: All valid points raised... however, there are always solutions to all problems. If you really needed to strip out UI properties from your view models, you could easily interface the relevant class types and provide mock implementations of those classes for testing. The chances are that that is not a requirement here as in most applications that users call MVVM.

Comment: *My question is where does it fit?* It fits just where it is now, doesn't it? All you're really changing is the need to use `IConverter` classes.

Comment: A couple of extra details I just picked up are that in some statuses the item background will flash (Probably use a storyboard) and / or have an audible alarm.  The user also has the ability to silence this functionality for a preset interval.  

Even so all this functionality feels very specific to the UI.  The flashing or sound and whether its silenced is all irrelevant to the rest of the system.  In truth I have no hard / fast standards I have to follow, but I'm working to establish them.  I hate to break them the first time it gets difficult.

Comment: A view model is supposed to be the model for the view. That means that it needs to provide whatever data the view requires. If you need properties for these effects, then add them to your view model. However, you can have different kinds of view model. A view model in the normal sense supplies all of the data for the view, but you can also have what some people also call a view model, which is a wrapper class for a business model class, but with extra properties for these UI related tasks. Typically, your 'main' view model would have one or more of these wrapper view models as properties.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create just one converter which will include all the conversion logic and return a new class which you will bind to:

```
public class MyNewConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Perform all required conversions here and return them as a new type of object
        return new
            {
                Data = ...,
                Fill = ...,
                Stroke = ...
            };
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is modify your `Path`'s `DataContext` property to use this converter.

```
<Viewbox MaxHeight="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Cursor="Hand">
    <WrapPanel>
        <Path Margin="2,2,2,2" StrokeThickness="2" DataContext="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource MyNewConverter}}">
            <Path.Data>
                <Binding Path="Data" Mode="OneWay" />
            </Path.Data>
            <Path.Fill>
                <Binding Path="Fill" Mode="OneWay" />
            </Path.Fill>
            <Path.Stroke>
                <Binding Path="Stroke" Mode="OneWay" />
            </Path.Stroke>
        </Path>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
    </WrapPanel>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: I like this idea a lot!  The only hitch I just ran into is some additional requirements that require flashing the background color (Storyboard maybe?) and audible notification on certain statuses.  I'm not sure how to kick off this types of UI events... Hmm, unless perhaps the storyboard can be turned off and on via a bindable attribute on a storyboard?  I'm looking into it now.

Comment: I used this solution for a while until I discovered something.  Returning a new anonymous type like this returns several bind errors.  It does work, but the errors are difficult to explain to a build manager and have an impact on performance.  Eventually I had to migrate away from this approach.

Comment: I used an anonymous type for simplicity. You could create a new class for this and avoid these errors.